# Core-icon style bug

Tags: css, svg

Why is there a vertical offset on the inner `svg` of `core-icon`s when the size is small?

http://jsbin.com/gasokepi/6/edit?html,output

**Update**: Looks like this has nothing to do with Polymer or web components. [This jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gasokepi/9/edit?html,output) just has an `svg` tag inside a `div` -- I even removed the indentation in the code in case it was a problem with a space being added because of inline-block-ness or something.

```
<div style="width: 12px; height: 12px; background: #ddd"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="background: aqua;"></svg></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `display: block` to your `svg` element it removes the extra space.

Comment: And I see this has [already been committed in master](https://github.com/Polymer/core-iconset-svg/commit/b8d8dc58a9ef749e159cee41698b02be4ff03146). Thanks!